# How to get the values from dynamically generated html textboxes in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to fetch the values from dynamically created html textboxes in  my aspx page. Now first I want to check if the textbox exists or not. If exists then I want to fetch values from these texboxes. Here is the code which I am using for creating textboxes dynamically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 2;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if (counter > 3) {
                alert("Limit Exceeds");
                return false;
            }
            var $wrap = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
            var dynamichtml = '<div id="div' + counter + '"><div class="mcity"><label> Leaving from</label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="auto"/>  </div><div class="mcity"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 1 + '" class="auto"/> </div><div class="mcity"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 11 + '" class="auto"/> </div>';
            $wrap.append(dynamichtml);
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }

            counter--;
            $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#div"+ counter).remove();
          //  $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#textbox" + counter+1).remove();


        });
  $(".auto").live("focus", function () {

                  $(this).autocomplete({

                      source: function (request, response) {
                          var textval = request.term; // $(this).val();
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              url: "Home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                              data: "{'code':'" + textval + "'}",
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function (data) {
                                  response(data.d);
                              },
                              error: function (result) {
                                  alert("Error");
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  });
              });
          });

</script>
```

This code is generating textboxes generating and I am fetching data from my database using json autocomplete process.After this I am trying to send the information to another page using javascript the code that I write for this is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("#btnPost").bind("click", function () {
              //Create a Form
              var $form = $("<form/>").attr("id", "data_form")
                            .attr("action", "Complete.aspx")
                            .attr("method", "post");
              $("body").append($form);

              //Append the values to be send
              AddParameter($form, "txtleft", $("#txtSearchleft").val());
              AddParameter($form, "txtright", $("#txtSearchright").val());

              //Send the Form
              $form[0].submit();
          });
      });
      function AddParameter(form, name, value) {
          var $input = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
                                .attr("name", name)
                                .attr("value", value);
          form.append($input);
      }
    </script>
```

This work fine for textboxes which placed default in my page. But for the textboxes that generate dynamically after these textboxes I dnt know how to send values of those textboxes to my next page

Javascript and asp.net experts please help me to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: As you are creating the Form dynamically, you need to generate the  controls and add it to the form. And then you can submit the form to the next page

Answer (score 0):

You can get the controls values using `FormCollection`. Note that it works on name rather than Id.

You need to keep the count and follow some naming convention for name of your controls.

Create a asp.net hidden field and keep the control count in that. And get according the values of the hidden field.

[Msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: if i am not wrong then we use FormCollecton in MVC. AM i right shekhar sir ? please clear my doubt. If I am wrong then tell me

Comment: @Azadchouhan It's in core `asp.net` and `mvc` is not mvc it's `asp.net mvc` so every feature which is in `asp.net` is in `asp.net mvc`

Answer (score 0):

well if you were to assign your form an id
you could just serialize your form and post it using ajax if you wanted

```
$.post("complete.aspx",$("#data_form").serialize(),function(response){
//react to the post here
});
```